# same hashId generated for different JSON string value

Tags: node.js, json, regex

i am using `json object` to generate hashId. Though it is generating different Ids for different object , I see when regular expression passed as value, they are generating the same hashID value, irrespective of values.

also how to handle such cases, going forward?

Here is the sample code

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

let j1 = {
    foo: /^hello$/i,
    bar: /^world$/i,
    john: /^1.0$/i,
    country: /^INDIA$/i
  };

let j2 = {
    foo: /^hello$/i,
    bar: /^world$/i,
    john: /^1.0$/i,
    country: /^CA$/i
  };

  let jsonId1 = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(JSON.stringify(j1)).digest('hex'),
  jsonId2 =  crypto.createHash('sha256').update(JSON.stringify(j2)).digest('hex');
```

Comment: Regular expressions don't have a JSON representation. `JSON.stringify()` returns the same string `{}` for all regular expressions.

Comment: is there any way to handle these particular scenario

Comment: use strings instead of regular expressions.